# How do I check if an input contains an isbn using javascript

Tags: javascript, search, isbn

I need a script that will test an input field's contents to see if it contains an ISBN. I found a few examples of this, but none of them strip the dashes. I need this to happen or my search results don't work. I have the else part of the script working if the field doesn't have an ISBN, but can't get the ISBN test to work. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
function search() {
    var textboxdata = $('#search').val();
        if (textboxdata contains an ISBN number, strip it of dashes and) {
            // perform ISBN search
            document.location.href = "http://myurl?search=" + textboxdata;
        }
        else { //perform other search
        }
 }
```

Comment: You should *really* be validating and formatting data on the server rather than the client.

Comment: to strip dashes, do `textboxdata = textboxdata.replace(/-/g, '');`

Comment: Matt, you are right, but also it is really nice to have an input change color or something like that before they submit a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this Wikipedia article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number

Should give you some insight into how to validate an ISBN number.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the algorithms given in the Wikipedia article, here's a simple javascript function for validating 10- and 13-digit ISBNs:

```
var isValidIsbn = function(str) {

    var sum,
        weight,
        digit,
        check,
        i;

    str = str.replace(/[^0-9X]/gi, '');

    if (str.length != 10 && str.length != 13) {
        return false;
    }

    if (str.length == 13) {
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            digit = parseInt(str[i]);
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                sum += 3*digit;
            } else {
                sum += digit;
            }
        }
        check = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;
        return (check == str[str.length-1]);
    }

    if (str.length == 10) {
        weight = 10;
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            digit = parseInt(str[i]);
            sum += weight*digit;
            weight--;
        }
        check = (11 - (sum % 11)) % 11
        if (check == 10) {
            check = 'X';
        }
        return (check == str[str.length-1].toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bruno It worked for me using your test ISBN (which appears to be valid).  I opened the console window in Chrome developer tools, pasted the code for the isValidIsbn function given above, then ran isValidIsbn("9781906230166") and got the result "true".

Comment: This code only checks the check-digit. This does not mean the ISBN is valid. (Test: `"978-1-906-230-166"` Should return `false` whilst `"978-1-906230-16-6"` should return `true`. Maybe rename this function to `checkDigit()`?

Comment: @Bruno Good point!  I was only interested in the checksum, but according to the spec, "The elements must each be separated clearly by hyphens or
spaces when displayed in human readable form.  ISBN 978-0-571-08989-5 or ISBN 978 0 571 08989 5".  It also says, "Note: The use of hyphens or spaces has no lexical significance and is purely to enhance
readability."  So it looks like the ISBN is *valid* without hyphens, but you should include the hyphens when displaying an ISBN to a user.  (see section 4 of https://www.isbn-international.org/sites/default/files/ISBN%20Manual%202012%20-corr.pdf)

Comment: That is awesome, I did not know that. But it is still just a check digit. For example this number will return `True`: `isValidIsbn("8781906230166")`;

Comment: Since ISBN 13's currently always start with 978,  adding a check for /^978/ to the ISBN 13 check would help reject an number of scanner errors when scanning a book's barcode.

Comment: @JohnK That is probably a good idea.  A few places are also starting to use the 979 prefix (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISBN_identifier_groups#Identifiers_of_the_979-_prefix)

Comment: Nice solution. Can I use this in a project under GPL?

Comment: @Denis, thanks!  All code posted to Stack Overflow is licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Comment: @DerekKurth, yes, I know. The problem is that my project is under GPLv3, which is not compatible with CC-BY-SA 3.0 (CC-BY-SA 4.0 would be compatible though.). That's why I was asking for explicit permission. (Even if Code on Stack Overflow is usually CC-BY-SA you, as the creator, can still license it under different terms.) In the meantime, I have put a working solution together, but yours is much more elegant...

Comment: @Denis Interesting!  Well, I don't know the implications of using the different licenses, but you (and anyone else) are welcome to use my solution, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a js library available for checking ISBN10 and ISBN13 formatting: [isbnjs](https://code.google.com/p/isbnjs/) as well as [isbn-verify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isbn-verify)

---

Edit 2/2/17 - previous link was to Google Code, some updated current links:
- [npm for isbn-verify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isbn-verify)
- [npm for isbnjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isbnjs)
- [Github project](https://github.com/yieme/isbnjs)

Answer (score 1):

Derek's code fails for this ISBN ==> "0756603390"

It's because the check digit will end up as 11.

incorrect == >   check = 11 - (sum % 11);
correct ==>      check = (11 - (sum % 11)) %11;

I tested the new code against 500 ISBN10s.

Comment: Good catch!  I tested this out, and you are right.  I have updated the code in my answer to use your change.